# SwiftUI voice over keyboard navigation for macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, voiceover

Is there a way to change the default key combination voice over uses to move the focus of the reader between elements on macOS? On iOS it's just various forms of multi-gesture inputs that are already pretty intuitive, but on macOS it seems to be ctrl+option+arrow_key or ctrl+option+shift+arrow_key and this is by far NOT as intuitive as something like being able to use the Tab key to navigate between elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the VO key (ctrl+opt) but you can assign other keys to do the same action.

[Assign VoiceOver commands to keyboard or keypad keys on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/voiceover/vo14096/mac)

VoiceOver is quite different than PC based screen readers (JAWS, NVDA, Narrator). It does have a learning curve and might not seem intuitive, but visually impaired users have been using it for a long time.

If you have a trackpad, you can turn on the [Commander](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/voiceover/cpvoutpcmdr/mac) and do the same gestures (such as swipe right) on the trackpad like you can on the iphone.